# Can I string along functions in an if statement and return a single variable?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm curious if it's possible to string along a couple possibilities for a function in an if statement, link them to a single variable and return the one that works, if any.

The following doesn't work, but it demonstrates the idea.  I'd like the below to return `2` since the function `myFn()` only returns true when `2` is passed to it.

But instead the following returns `true: 1`.

```
if ($b = myFn(1) || $b = myFn(2) || $b = myFn(3)) {
    echo 'true: ' . $b;
} else {
    echo 'false: ' . $b;
}

function myFn($a) {
    if ($a == 2) return $a;
    return false;
}
```

Short of adding a series of `elseif`s, is there a way to string the functions in a series of `OR`s while only returning the successful one?

codepad: http://codepad.org/ldiCxY4j

Comment: IMHO - I think it is a bad idea to include assignment in the if clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap each assignment in parenthesis:

`(($b = myFn(1)) || ($b = myFn(2)) || ($b = myFn(3)))`

See: [PHP operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

When using [logical](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) operators, PHP coerces the result to boolean. Without the extra parens, it echoes `'1'` because echoing coerces `true` to `'1'`.

You may be better off using a loop:

```
/**
 * Get the first $array value that passes the $test, or else null.
 * @return mixed|null 
 */
function find ($array, $test) {
    foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
        if (call_user_func($test, $value, $index, $array))
            return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, any idea why the parentheses are necessary?

Comment: I'm assuming that by wrapping them in parens, you avoid the `true` value you'd get as a result of a successful assignment and instead get the value of $b instead?

Comment: @SurrealDreams That's not quite true. What is actually happening is `$b = (myFn(1) || $b = myFn(2) || $b = myFn(3))`, which is the same as `$b = (myFn(1) || myFn(2) || myFn(3))` so $b is actually being set to true (which has the int value of 1 (the boolean is casted to a int in the str concatenation, so that is why it prints a 1))

Comment: @Niko See edited answer and http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @Supericy Exactly. Note that PHP and JavaScript handle that line differently. In PHP `$b` becomes a boolean. In JavaScript `$b` becomes the first truthy value.

Answer (score 2):

For such concatenations of assignments PHP has the `or` operator, which is the same as `||` but with [less precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `=`. This means that

```
if ($b = myFn(1) or $b = myFn(2) or $b = myFn(3))
```

is treated like:

```
if (($b = myFn(1)) or ($b = myFn(2)) or ($b = myFn(3)))
```

**while**

```
if ($b = myFn(1) || $b = myFn(2) || $b = myFn(3))
```

is treated like:

```
if ($b = (myFn(1) || $b = (myFn(2) || $b = myFn(3))))
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about the `or` operator in PHP.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you've seen abominations like `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('horrible');` - that makes use of the same mechanism.